# Spring Boot: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

This is the error:

[image: avatar]
[image: avatar]

When I use spring security in Spring Boot, I get an error. I've searched google, and read the Spring documentation, but I am still having trouble. I do not understand what this error means.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace as well? I couldn't see the end of the stacktrace from the screen shot.

Comment: Next time, pls add code and log messages to your post as text. It is easier to copy/paste for debugging/reviewing issue.

Comment: give full error as text but not screenshot would help more.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, that your instance of `UserDetailsServiceImpl` is `null`, based on what I see in your screenshot.

To really help you, please add the stacktrace. Not as a screenshot but textual.

Comment: Please update your question, do not "answer" it. Do NOT use screenshots to show us the code, insert code directly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: my pom]

[image: my web sec config]

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

UserDetailsServicelmpl userDetailsService;


AuthEntryPointjwt unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

[image: user details service impl]

@Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

```
@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username"+ username));
    return  UserDetailslmpl.build(user);
}
```

[image: userdetailsservice]

Comment: You have published this as an answer when it is not. Edit your own post and add there, thanks.